# Tmux sending wrong keycodes for "ctrl + arrowkey" and "ctrl + shift + arrowkey"

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, tmux, iterm2

### The problem

I upgraded to MacOS 13.5 today and immediately noticed this issue. Inside of tmux (running in iterm2) when I perform `ctrl + arrow-key` or `ctrl + shift + arrow-key` the wrong keycodes are sent.

For example, for the up-arrow, the correct codes are:

```
ctrl + up-arrow: \e[1;5A

ctrl + shift + up-arrow: \e[1;6A
```

But instead it's sending:

```
ctrl + up-arrow: \e[1;6A

ctrl + shift + up-arrow: \e[1;7A
```

I verified this by disabling all of my tmux keybindings that used the shortcuts and typed in the key sequences while running `cat`.

Consequently `ctrl + arrow-key` is acting like `ctrl + shift + arrow-key`, and `ctrl + shift + arrow-key` is doing nothing (sending an unhandled keycode).

Outside of tmux (in iterm2) the correct keycodes are being sent, so the problem is isolated to tmux. The issue also appears if I run tmux using the built-in MacOS terminal instead of iterm2.

### Imperfect fix

My hacky workaround was to modify my iterm2 profile key mappings to:

```
ctrl + up-arrow: \e[1;4A

ctrl + shift + up-arrow: \e[1;5A

...same for other arrow-keys
```

This forced tmux to send the correct keycodes, so it seems like the keycodes are just offset by one for some reason. The downside to this fix is that it breaks `ctrl + arrow-key` outside of tmux since `\e[1;4A` isn't a keycode that's typically accepted.

### Software versions

Besides the MacOS upgrade the rest of my software stack has not been upgraded in several months.

I'm using `xterm-256color` in both iterm2 and tmux. I tried `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on` but it didn't help.

- tmux 2.7
- iterm2 3.4.20 (upgraded today as part of debugging, but reproed on older version too)